# Concise argument: $[f]$ in the ultrafilter that realizes $\Sigma$?

Tags: logic, model-theory, filters

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a countable language and $\mathcal{A}_i$ be $\mathcal{L}$-structures.

Let $\mathcal{A}=\prod_{i \in \omega} \mathcal{A}_i/\mathcal{U}$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter.

Let $S=\{[f_k]:k \in \omega\}$ where $[f_i] \neq [f_j] \in A$ when $i \neq j$.

Let $\Sigma(u)$ be a complete 1-type of $T=Th(\mathcal{A}_S)$, where $\mathcal{A}_S$ is the corresponding structure to $\mathcal{A}$ in the language obtained by adding one constant symbol for each element of $S$.

> Q: Can we find a $[f] \in A$ that realizes $\Sigma$?

I am still new to ultrafilters, so I would like to do this from scratch as much as possible, not citing theorems except one's that I've already proven. I know Los's Theorem (although I don't know if it helps here) and I know that a non-principal ultrafilter must contain all the cofinite sets, but that's about it. **Also I would like to do this as concisely as possible, hopefully with an argument that takes half a page or so.**

Comment: The answer is yes: this property is called  "$\aleph_1$-saturated" (every $1$-type over a  set of size $<\aleph_1$ is realized), and it is a very well-known property of ultraproducts. What are you looking for here? A reference a proof? A hint so you can try to prove it yourself?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'm aware of a proof in this paper http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Gannon.pdf , but he proves it as a corollary of another theorem (which I don't particularly need), and that theorem takes an entire page to prove. I'm wondering if there's a more concise way.

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't include that context in the question... You'll get better answers if you explain exactly what you're looking for and why?

Answer (score 3):

Assume WLOG that the $\mathcal{A}_i$s are disjoint. Changing notation a bit, I'll write "$\mathcal{A}^S$" for your "$\mathcal{A}_S$." The reason for this notational change is that it lets us more cleanly emulate the same construction on the level of the individual factors: let $\mathcal{A}_i^S$ be the expansion of $\mathcal{A}_i$ by a constant symbol $c_k$ naming $f_k(i)$, for each $k\in\omega$. Note that we have $\mathcal{A}^S=\prod\mathcal{A}^S_i/\mathcal{U}$.

Now the idea is that a *sequence of elements of the $\mathcal{A}_i^S$s* $g$ getting better and better at realizing $\Sigma(u)$ in the individual $\mathcal{A}_i^S$s translates to $[g]_\mathcal{U}$ as an *element of the ultraproduct* actually realizing all of $\Sigma(u)$ in the ultraproduct. Fix some enumeration of the formulas in $\Sigma(u)$. Given $i\in\omega$ and $a\in\mathcal{A}_i^S$, say that the **$i$-goodness of $a$** is the largest $n\in\omega+1$ such that $a$ realizes in $\mathcal{A}^S_i$ the first $n$ formulas in $\Sigma(u)$. Note that for each $i\in\omega$ we can find an $a_i\in\mathcal{A}_i^S$ such that *either* the $i$-goodness of $a_i$ is $\ge i$, *or* the $i$-goodness of $a_i$ is maximal amongst all elements of $\mathcal{A}_i^S$; let $g$ be a sequence whose $i$th term is such an $a_i$.

At this point you can show that, for each formula $\varphi\in\Sigma(u)$, $\mathcal{U}$-many $i$s have $g(i)$ realizing $\varphi$ in $\mathcal{A}_i^S$. Los' Theorem then tells us that $[g]_\mathcal{U}$ realizes $\Sigma(u)$ in $\mathcal{A}^S$. **This may be easier to see if you first consider the case of an ultra*power*, that is, an ultraproduct where all the $\mathcal{A}_i$s are isomorphic; this has the benefit of guaranteeing that we can always find arbitrarily high $i$-goodness elements of $\mathcal{A}_i^S$.**

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Try to show that, for each $k\in\omega$, for $\mathcal{U}$-many $i$s there is an element of $\mathcal{A}_i^S$ which has $i$-goodness at least $k$. (HINT: ultrafilters are closed under finite intersections.)

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Start by thinking about a single formula: do you see why, for each specific formula $\varphi\in\Sigma(u)$, there must be $\mathcal{U}$-many $i$ such that $\mathcal{A}_i^S$ has an element witnessing $\varphi$? If you get that, you can prove the larger goal by induction + closure of $\mathcal{U}$ under finite intersections (+, I suppose, the fact that $\varphi,\psi\in\Sigma\implies \varphi\wedge\psi\in\Sigma$).

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Well, since $\Sigma(u)$ is a type over the ultraproduct, we have that the ultraproduct satisfies $\exists x\varphi(x)$. Now apply Los.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager No. Los' theorem merely says that since the ultraproduct satisfies the first-order sentence $\exists x\varphi(x)$, $\mathcal{U}$-many (but not necessarily all!) factors must also satisfy $\exists x\varphi(x)$.

Comment: Say our enumeration of $\Sigma$ is $\phi_0,\phi_1 \dots$. We have shown $\{i: {\mathcal{A}_i}^S \models \phi_j[a]$ for some $a \}$ is in $\mathcal{U}$ (where $0 \leq j \leq k$). But can we show $\{i: {\mathcal{A}_i}^S \models \phi_j[a_i] \}$ is in $\mathcal{U}$? (Earlier, I thought the former set was a subset of the other so I said "yes," but now I'm not so sure.)

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Yes. I think it will help to consider just the first two formulas $\varphi_0,\varphi_1$ in $\Sigma$. Since $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_1$ are in $\Sigma$, their conjunction $\varphi_0\wedge\varphi_1$ is also in $\Sigma$. So $\mathcal{U}$-many $\mathcal{A}_i^s$s have an element satisfying $\varphi_0\wedge\varphi_1$. This means that $\mathcal{U}$-many $a_i$s satisfy both $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_1$ (since we pick the $a_i$s "greedily:" if $i>2$ then $a_i$ will satisfy $\varphi_0\wedge\varphi_1$ in $\mathcal{A}_i^S$ if such an element exists at all).

Comment: Note the crucial role of passing to the conjunction here: just because $\mathcal{A}_i^S$ has an element satisfying $\varphi_0$ and an element satisfying $\varphi_1$ doesn't mean that it has an element satisfying $\varphi_0\wedge\varphi_1$.

Comment: It may actually be more intuitively to shift from a full enumeration $(\varphi_i)_{i\in\omega}$ of $\Sigma$ to the related sequence of formulas $(\bigwedge_{j<i}\varphi_j)_{i\in\omega}$. This latter sequence of formulas has all the power of the former, but is a bit nicer in that an element satisfying the $i$th formula in a given structure automatically satisfies all "earlier" formulas in that same structure.